# Django: How to access STATIC_FILES that I set in settings.py in another view?

Tags: python, django, import, static, settings

I keep getting the following error: name 'STATIC_DIRS' is not defined, when I try to access it in a view from my settings.py. What do I import to make this work in my views?

Answer (score 2):

You can import the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

And then you can access variables set in your settings file by doing `settings.variable`